# PhpStorm Space and Align settings in 'Code style'

Tags: phpstorm, settings

I'm trying to set the spaces and the alignment for code formatting in PhpStorm but it doesn't work.

In the screenshot you can see that the box is checked but in the code the setting is not applied. I have also some problems with the spaces, I ticked all the boxes in "Space Within" section but when I write an `if()` statement, for example, the editor doesn't add the space between the parenthesis. Same problem for the semicolon at the end, is never added automatically.

I've tried to change the settings in "File->Settings and File->Default Settings", in Default scheme and Project Scheme with no success.

Thank you in advance for your help!

[image: PhpStorm settings]

Comment: `Code | Reformat Code...`. Such settings are not applied to normal typing. It may only be applied automatically when IDE performs certain actions, like code completion etc.

Comment: @LazyOne also with code completion it doesn't add the spaces, for example if I start to write the if statement and then I hit Enter to confirm, it add the if statement without spaces ( if() and not if(  ).
Anyway I don't see any advantage if it works only in certain conditions. It's an editor, I write the code in

Comment: Try `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` for completion/after completion -- it will behave better in this regard. TBH -- to advise something I will need to see specific code/situation. I'm either not noticing such nuances .. or it works acceptable as for my liking. P.S. You may also create own Live Templates (code snippets) that will have desired code/editing points/formatting already present.

Comment: With `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` it only adds curly brackets if I try with the if statement, no spaces...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Array initializers**

There is no way (AFAIK) around using `Code | Reformat Code`. The default shortcut for this is `Ctrl+Alt+L` (aka `Alt Gr+L`), works either for the whole file or for the currently selected code.

If your code style rules are set up well, you can see this as your
"save" action and do it as frequently as you need.

**If statements**

As @LazyOne suggested, your can also make use of [`Live Templates`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-live-templates.html) to achieve what you want in this case.

In `Settings | Editor | Live Templates`, add an entry to the `PHP` section, call it `if` and use the following template text:

```
if ( $CONDITION$ ) {
    $THEN$
}
```

Note: I've added a tab character before `$THEN$`, feel free to change it to spaces if needed.

Now if you use `if` and hit `Ctrl+Enter`, PHPStorm should suggest your live template before the default `if`, so you can select it and then navigate through the template variables using `Tab`.